# How to run multiple timers that also update a UI once per second in Kotlin / Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

To simplify the issue a bit, I'd like to run multiple timers while an app is running (and to update those timers when the app is re-opened). If you know what an Idle Game is, that's what I'm attempting to achieve, or even just being able to run multiple alarm clocks might be fairly similar code.

Each time a new data object (that's stored in my local Room DB) is created, a new timer should be created that counts down from an arbitrary number (let's say 100).

For each new object, that timer should remain unique, so if you created 3 timers, they should all run independently.

When they hit 0, no matter which screen or activity you're on, they should trigger a DB call to do some work (doesn't matter what), and then (and this is the part I'm most stuck on) update the UI on the fly without user interaction.

So a user hits a button a few times:

- Creates 3 timers
- When each timer runs out, let's say it adds "1" to a UI field
- It should be 3 after all timers are finished running (without further user interaction)

I'd also love for the timers to be able to run while the user is not on the app specifically, or at least update when the user comes back. This isn't strictly necessary, as I COULD do it by checking the current time, and storing a start time and end time, but I'm not sure that's the best pattern to go on.

I've attempted to use a WorkManager to accomplish this, but couldn't get the UI to update properly, and I'm not entirely sure I'm running multiple UNIQUE timers as the WorkManager appears a little difficult to debug

Here's some sample code where my job isn't showing the timer updating:

```
@Composable
fun JobList() {
    val jobViewModel: JobViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val jobList = jobViewModel.getAllJobs()
    val jobValues = jobList.collectAsState(emptyList())

    Column {
        jobValues.value.forEach { value ->
            Button(onClick = { deleteJob(jobViewModel, value) }) {
                Text("Delete me")
            }
            val jobTimer = jobViewModel.getJobTimerDisplay(value.jobId)
            val jobTimerValue = jobTimer.collectAsState("")
            JobTimer(totalTime = jobTimerValue.value)
            Text(text = "Job Level: ${value.jobLevel} : ${value.name} : Stealth: ${value.stealthRequirement}, Brute: ${value.bruteRequirement}")
        }
    }
}
```

My jobs are updating if I add to them via a click handler elsewhere, the lines

```
val jobList = jobViewModel.getAllJobs()
val jobValues = jobList.collectAsState(emptyList())
```

But the timer is not ticking:

```
val jobTimer = jobViewModel.getJobTimerDisplay(value.jobId)
val jobTimerValue = jobTimer.collectAsState("")
JobTimer(totalTime = jobTimerValue.value)
```

The timer WILL update (for all items) if I add a new job, but not when the timer itself updates via a WorkManager. I can also observe the timer data in the DB being updated, so I know it's being updated properly, the UI is not reflecting this however

Here is the WorkManager code that does the update:

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    var working = true
    while (working) {
        delay(1001)
        val currentTime = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
        val jobId = inputData.getString("jobId")
        val job = jobId?.let { AppDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext).jobDao().loadById(it) }
        if (job != null) {
            AppDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext).jobDao()
                .updateJob(job.copy(jobTimer = currentTime))
        } else {
            working = false
        }

    }

    return Result.success()
}
```

Comment: I think the most robust solution is whenever a button is pressed update some game state object you have in memory with the start time and other identifying info. Maybe you keep a mutable List of some data class that has start time and button ID, for example. Also start a timer (coroutine, TimerTask, postDelayed, etc. take your pick) that will execute the action when it runs down. In `onStop`, cancel all these timers and in `onStart`, start new timers for button presses in your list. Remove from your list when the timer runs out. Save and reload your list to disk in onDestroy/onCreate.

Comment: After a little more digging, I am creating unique WorkManager tasks for each click. My main problem is that the UI is not updating when the Room DB is updated. I added a section of code explaining a bit more above

Comment: Also in onStart, before you start new timers, check if any timers already expired and run their actions directly since they no longer need timers. This requires no use of services or WorkManager or AlarmManager, so it is simple.

Comment: Not enough code there for me to tell why you wouldn't be seeing them update.

Comment: What other code would you need to see? The WorkManager code that does the DB update?

Comment: I was going to say your ViewModel code. But I missed the part about you updating the Database in a WorkManager and viewing it in your UI. I don't think that will necessarily work because the database changes made in the WorkManager probably won't be picked up by Room if that's what you're using. I haven't done much with WorkManager yet, but I am guessing it runs in a separate process from the UI portion of your app.

Comment: I highly discourage using WorkManager for this, though. Doing all this self-contained in a single process is way simpler. It is hard to communicate between UI and Services/WorkManager/AlarmManager. And it doesn't make sense to use those because then they rely on waking up the phone and doing stuff that is not needed until the next time the user opens the UI. Waste of battery and resources.

Comment: True, I thought about making it simpler and using the viewModel and a coroutine, but WorkManager will spawn new threads if necessary and runs on a background thread by default, increasing speed and reliability (especially since I might be updating two dozen items every second)

Comment: I think you misunderstand what threads accomplish. Threads have nothing to do with reliability. It still has to update UI on the main thread, so the background thread isn't actually doing anything except writing to your database, but coroutines also write to the database on a background thread. If you use my suggestion from my first comment, you will only be accessing the database once in `onStart` and `onStop`, so it won't have any performance penalty regardless of how many timers are going at once.

Comment: Ideally, I'd also like the app to run in the background when the user doesn't have the app focused. Changing to a basic coroutine would require a restructure of MOST of the code and also necessitate state saving and updating (although I'll have some of that later)

Comment: Maybe you can get it to work with WorkManager, but I'm not personally familiar enough with it to help further. But I challenge you to consider, what is the app doing in the background that can't be done once the UI reappears? Is it doing something world-time dependent, like fetching something from the Internet or interacting with other apps at a specific time? Android discourages doing background work unless absolutely necessary, as it keeps the phone awake and wastes battery.

Comment: I'll give switching it to a coroutine a shot! Still curious as to if there's an answer to the Room DB / UI update though :)